# creating friend graph

Tags: sql, graph, friend

I want to create a friend list for my website which is supposed to be stored in a database table, following is the table structure I think should best serve the purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE `sdt_friend_graph` (
  `user` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` ENUM('requested','accepted') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `requested_on` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `accepted_on` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`,`friend`)
)
```

just want to find out if my approach is ok, or is there any better way to do this to make it more efficient, I'm open to suggestions.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

your table structure looks fine, i would just add user as an AUTO_INCREMENT field and change the name to friendid... just for semantics.

Comment: how can I make `user` AUTO_INCREMENT it is supposed to hold the `user_id` who is generating the friend request and could be random I think, please correct me if I'm wrong or misunderstood you. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You are right, if you want to store existing user don't need auto increment, i got confused yes indeed you have correct. 

One thing i missed is the ENUM field maybe adding declined to the list would help.

Cheers.